# Pedestrian routing using pgRouting

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgsql, dijkstra

I'm new to pgRouting and I want to implement a pedestrian routing system. I've already implemented a routing system using pgRouting, PostGIS, GeoServer, OSM data and OpenLayers 3 and it uses Dijkstra to find the routes.

My problem is I don't know how to specify that the routing I want my system to do is for pedestrians.

Comment: we're using distance and a sidewalk layer for our pedestrian routing ... so it's all about distance rather than time

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry I'm new in this kind of stuff. How can I use a sidewalk layer for my routing?

Comment: Well first - do you have sidewalk data? Otherwise, you'll have to make some assumptions about your street data using speed limits, etc. to figure out if someone would/could walk on it...

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is to get proper data - assuming that in OSM there is some you have to create a network from it. I'm using osm2po which is producing graph with info about assignation of road-types. You can configure it in config file.

```
wtr.tag.highway.living_street =  1, 63, 7,   car|bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.pedestrian =     1, 62, 5,   bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.track =          1, 71, 10,  bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.path =           1, 72, 10,  bike|foot
wtr.tag.highway.cycleway =       1, 81, 15,  bike
wtr.tag.highway.footway =        1, 91, 5,   foot
wtr.tag.highway.steps =          1, 92, 5,   foot
```

Osm2po produces SQL script you can import into database via psql -f, then in your routing function you can use flags column to select for routing input only edges assignated for pedestrians (third bit of flags set to 1)

```
SELECT
    sum(pgr.km) AS km, sum(pgr.cost) AS cost, ST_Union(pgr.geom_way) AS geom 
FROM 
    pgr_poland pgr, 
    (SELECT * FROM pgr_astar('select id, source,target, cost, reverse_cost, x1, y1, x2, y2 from pgr_poland where flags::bit(3) & B''100'' = B''100'' ', <<start_edge_i>>, <<stop_edge_i>>, true, true)) AS rte  
WHERE 
    pgr.id = rte.id2;
```

Of course following @mapBaker it is wiser to use distance as a cost than time.